# Perl & Sed string substitute in several expressions

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I would like to make string substitution in a non-greedy match fashion

- Remove all leading and trailing dashes, apostrophes (when these symbols are found in the middle of the word, they must be preserved)
- Transform multiple spaces into 1 space

Example:

```
--ONE   Tw'o--   -333-   -'FO-UR'
```

must become

```
ONE Tw'o 333 FO-UR
```

I cannot get exactly the result. Can you please help me to correct my perl and sed syntax below?

```
$ echo "--ONE   Tw'o--   -333-   -'FO-UR'" \
  | perl -pe "s/[-']+(.+?)/\1/g"           \
  | perl -pe "s/(.+?)[-']+/\1/g"           \
  | perl -pe "s/\s+/ /g"

Result (perl): "ONE Two 333 FOUR"

$ echo "--ONE   Tw'o--   -333-   -'FO-UR'" \
  | sed -r -e "s/[-']+(.+?)/\1/g"          \
    -e "s/(.+)[-']+/\1/g"                  \
    -e "s/\s+/ /g"

Result (sed): "ONE Tw'o-- -333- -'FO-UR"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the perl version:

```
echo "--ONE   Tw'o--   -333-   -'FO-UR'" | perl -ne "s|-'||g; s|'-||g; s|^'||; s|'$||; s|^-+||; s|-+$||; s|-+\s+| |g; s|\s+-+| |g; s|\s+| |g; s|\s+$||; print;"

ONE Tw'o 333 FO-UR
```

The sed version is basically identical:

```
echo "--ONE   Tw'o--   -333-   -'FO-UR'" | sed -r -e "s|-'||g; s|'-||g; s|^'||; s|'$||; s|^-+||; s|-+$||; s|-+\s+| |g; s|\s+-+| |g; s|\s+| |g; s|\s+$||;"

ONE Tw'o 333 FO-UR
```

Annotations for the regular expressions used:

```
s|-'||g;     # Remove dash followed by quote everywhere
s|'-||g;     # Remove quote followed by dash everywhere
s|^'||;      # Remove leading quote
s|'$||;      # Remove trailing quote
s|^-+||;     # Remove leading dash characters
s|-+$||;     # Remove trailing dash characters
s|-+\s+| |g; # Replace dash characters followed by whitespace with 1 space everywhere
s|\s+-+| |g; # Replace whitespace followed by dash characters with 1 space everywhere
s|\s+| |g;   # Replace multiple spaces with 1 space
s|\s+$||;    # Remove trailing spaces
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your help. Appreciated very much you went to the trouble to give the solution for both perl and sed. This code is amazing, correct results without using any back reference substitution.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy using lookarounds in `perl`:

```
s='"asd,f",,,"as,df","asdf"asdf"'
perl -pe 's/(?<!\w)-|-(?!\w)//g' <<< "$s"
ONE Tw'o 333 'FO-UR'

(?<!\w)- # Lookbehind meaning match - if not preceded by a word character
|        # regex alternation
(?!\w)-  # Lookahead meaning match - if not followed by a word character
```